# How do I safely unwrap this URL optional which i call from my database in Firebase?

Tags: ios, swift, url, firebase, option-type

This is the screen shot as you can see it shows error as I forced unwrapped and some urls are empty:

[image]

How can I safely unwrap this URL so I don't have to force unwrap ?

Code:

```
func tableView    (_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection 
section: Int) -> Int 
{
        return players.count
    }
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: 
IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: 
Reusable.reuseIdForMain) as! CustomCell
        cell.nameLabel.text = players[indexPath.row].name
        cell.otherInfo.text = players[indexPath.row].otherInfo


if let url = players[indexPath.row].imageUrl{
            cell.profileImage.load.request(with: URL(string:url)!)

    }


    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should check for the value of the URL itself after checking the string. Both strings will be safely unwrapped this way.

```
if let urlString = players[indexPath.row].imageUrl,
    let url = URL(string: urlString) {
    cell.profileImage.load.request(with: url)
}
```

Comment: I used this methodology, and sometimes the first image in my collectionView wouldn't load (failed to the ELSE part of the if let) even tho the model had the string of the url just fine.  WHY?????

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
if let imageUrl = players[indexPath.row].imageUrl as? String{
     let url = URL(string: imageUrl)
     if let url = url {
            cell.profileImage.load.request(with: url)
     }
  }
```

Comment: why did u check this if let url = url @DionizB

Comment: @DevTech if there is any data in url , `if let url = url ` will return true otherwise will return false

Answer (score 0):

Tomas Sengel's method works easiest and simplest; HOWEVER...

Sometimes images in my collectionView wouldn't load (failed to the ELSE part of the if-let) even tho the model downloaded (from Firebase) the string of the url just fine.

The reason was **some URLs have a space in the url string**, which the Apple method URL(string: ) doesn't handle properly (Apple should update it). To fix, either find/write a better method to convert strings to URL type, or replace spaces with %20.  literally. " " -> "%20" and then URL(string: ) won't fail the guard condition.

Answer (score -1):

Use Below code that will also resolved your problem for loading an image within nano second try this

```
extension UIImageView {
public func imageFromUrl(urlString: String) {
    if let url = NSURL(string: urlString) {
        let request = NSURLRequest(url: url as URL)
        NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request as URLRequest, queue: OperationQueue.main) { (response: URLResponse?, data: Data?, error: Error?) -> Void in
            if let imageData = data as NSData? {
                self.image = UIImage(data: imageData as Data)
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Uses

```
if players[indexPath.row].imageUrl != "" && players[indexPath.row].imageUrl != nil {
   cell.profileImage.imageFromUrl(urlString: players[indexPath.row].imageUrl)
}
```